# Renaming an enum value results in "Type Relation Not found"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to update TYPE with query:

```
ALTER TYPE public.enum_subscription_sub_frequency RENAME ATTRIBUTE "BI-WEEKLY" TO "BI_WEEKLY";
```

But it give me error `ERROR: relation "public.enum_subscription_sub_frequency" does not exist` but type is exist.

[image: freq]

Kind Help me to complete this.

Screen:

[image: c]

[image: ss]

Got Answer:

```
ALTER TYPE public.enum_subscription_sub_frequency RENAME VALUE 'BI-MONTHLY' TO 'BI_MONTHLY';
```

but i also need to alter multiple value of a TYPE?

Comment: three things to check: 1) is the type in the `public` schema? 2) is your sql client connected to the right db? 3) does your user have the proper permissions? (unlikely to be the error, but worth taking a look)

Comment: @JimJones Kindly check Edit question.

Comment: There is no need to add the solution to the question. The fact that an answer is accepted marks the question as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renaming a value of an enum is only supported starting with Postgres 10.

---

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertype.html#id-1.9.3.40.8) you have to use `rename VALUE`, not `rename attribute` to rename the value of an enum.

Enums values are also string constants, not identifiers. Therefore you need to enclose them in single quotes, not double quotes:

```
ALTER TYPE public.enum_subscription_sub_frequency RENAME VALUE 'BI-WEEKLY' TO 'BI_WEEKLY';
```

---

If you wonder why you get a "type ... does not exist" error with the wrong syntax:

When you use the option `RENAME ATTRIBUTE` this indicates that a "regular" object type should be changed, so Postgres looks for an "real" object type.

But an "enum type" is not an "object type" and therefor Postgres complains about "type xyz does not exist", rather than a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks it work. `ALTER TYPE public.enum_subscription_sub_frequency RENAME VALUE 'BI-WEEKLY' TO 'BI_WEEKLY';`

Comment: I also want to alter more than one value. Please suggest

Comment: [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertype.html) you can only rename one value at a time.

Comment: I am able to find there for multiple. Please edit in your query.Its Urgent

Comment: Please do not extend the scope of your question once you have an answer. [Ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead (but you already have an answer: you can not rename more than one enum value with a single ALTER TYPE statement)

Comment: Thanks for your answer a_horse_no_name.

Comment: this query solve my problem but when i run this in H2 database it gives me error. PLease suggest me for that.

Comment: is there any query that run in both h2 and postgresql database?

Comment: It give syntax error at `VALUE` in `postgres 9.6` but work fine in `Postgres 10.3`